# Program to compare int arrays not working

Tags: c, arrays

So, as part of uni work i had to create a lottery simulator. I have also used 2 functions in this program. get_lotto_draw creates a 6 element array with random nums between 1-49, find_matches should compare a user defined 6 element array with this random generated array, and keep track of how many matches are found. The program simulates playing the lotto once a weeks over a user specified number of years.

Main body:

```
const int WEEKS_IN_YEAR = 52;
int lottoCounter = 0;
years = years * WEEKS_IN_YEAR;

int match1 = 0;
int match2 = 0;
int match3 = 0;
int match4 = 0;
int match5 = 0;
int match6 = 0;

for(lottoCounter = 0; lottoCounter < years; lottoCounter++)
{
      int* x = get_lotto_draw(); //Use function to generate lottery numbers
      int* y = userNums;
      int found = find_matches(x, y);

      if(found == 1)
      {
               match1++;
      }

       if(found == 2)
      {
               match2++;
      }

       if(found == 3)
      {
               match3++;
      }

       if(found == 4)
      {
               match4++;
      }

       if(found == 5)
      {
               match5++;
      }

       if(found == 6)
      {
               match6++;
      }

      if(match6 != 0)
      {
                printf("Congratulations Roger, you've won the Jackpot!");
                break;
      }   
}

printf("Matched 1 number %d times", match1);
printf("\nMatched 2 number %d times", match2);
printf("\nMatched 3 number %d times", match3);
printf("\nMatched 4 number %d times", match4);
printf("\nMatched 5 number %d times", match5);
printf("\nMatched 6 number %d times", match6);

free(arrayPointer);
```

get_lotto_draw function:

```
int* get_lotto_draw() //Returns an array of six random lottery numbers 1-49
{
     int min = 1;
     int max = 49;
     int counter = 0;

     srand(time(NULL)); //Set seed for rand as current time

     int *arrayPointer = malloc(6 * sizeof(int)); //Clear space for arrayPointer

     for(counter = 0; counter <= 5; counter++)
     {
                 int x1 = 1;

                 while(x1)
                 {
                          int temp = rand()%(max-min)+min; //Gives random number range between 1-49 inclusive
                          int i = 0;

                          for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                          {
                              if( arrayPointer[i] == temp)
                              {
                                break;
                              }
                          } 

                          if(i == counter)
                          {
                             x1=0;
                             arrayPointer[counter] = temp;
                          }
                  }
     }  
     return arrayPointer;
}
```

find_matches function:

```
int find_matches(int * array1, int * array2)
{
    int* x = array1;
    int* y = array2;
    int found = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
          for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
          {
                if(x[i] == y[j])
                {
                     found++;
                }
          }
    }
    return found;  
}
```

The problem im having is that the " Matched 1 number %d time" and so on are not working, they just give me 0 values. I think the problem is somewhere in main because my functions were working earlier. Thanks for your time.

*EDIT*

I added this code to main:

```
int myArray[6] = {1, 23, 42, 32, 4, 17};
int* x = userNums;
int* y = myArray;
int found = find_matches(x, y);
printf("matches: %d", found);
```

And this works fine. If i enter 3 number that are present in myArray, found returns as 3 and so on.

Comment: `match1` to `match6` better lived in an array which would greatly simplify the the main body (< 20 lines).

Comment: Incidentally, you have a memory leak. You malloc() memory in get_lotto_draw(), within your loop, and you never free that memory.

Comment: And move `srand(time(NULL));` to the beginning of `main()`. It has no business being in its current location.

Comment: Thanks,  have fixed srand and the memory leak in my program.

Comment: You say they were working earlier. What did you change when they stopped working? And what did you see when you printed out the contents of the `x` and `y` arrays to verify that they were correct?

Comment: @dat_guy based on your update, you've made the memory leak worse with this change. First -- you're calling `free(*arrayPointer);` but the proper way to free it is without dereferencing it, so this will likely cause you to crash. Second, you cannot free the buffer and then plan to use its contents later (which is what you do by returning the pointer). Free it somewhere else, after you're done with it.

Comment: You're only getting a new lotto draw once per year. Besides this, moving the `srand` should have fixed your problem.

Comment: @Allbeert Thanks for spotting that mistake, I multiplied by no. of weeks in the wrong var.

Comment: `temp = rand()%(max-min)+min;` : gives 1-48 , is not 1-49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took all the advice from the comments left on my question. I placed my random seed at the start of main instead of in the function, fixed the amount of times the lottery was drawn each year, and placed free(arrayPointer) after returning arrayPointer. After implementing all of these fixes, my program is now working fine, thanks to all who contributed!